# Unable to connect to Scylla API server: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) on MAC OS

Tags: docker, scala, scylla

I'm new at Scylla DB and i was just creating Nodes using Commands given in documentation.
What happens is when i create Two nodes no matter what they're referred as, they happen to connect to Scylla DB server, but when it comes to third node i face this error.
For Example
After successfully creating Node_X by using
`docker run --name Node_X -d scylladb/scylla:5.2.0 --overprovisioned 1 --smp 1`
I checked Node Tool Status for Node_X using

```
docker exec -it Node_X nodetool status
```

and got

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.0.3  1.03 MB    256          ?       57765ee9-bb4b-4287-a7c1-b47878e22926  rack1
UN  172.17.0.2  256 KB     256          ?       bce9e5b7-e5ab-47aa-88d3-3413fd6e4980  rack1
```

Same goes with Node_Y which is made using command `docker run --name Node_Y -d scylladb/scylla:5.2.0 --seeds="$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' Node_X)" --overprovisioned 1 --smp 1` which is running perfectly fine. Giving it's nodetool status successfully.

BUT when it comes to Node_Z (Third Node) it's giving error.
For Creating i used this command

```
docker run --name Node_Z -d scylladb/scylla:5.2.0 --seeds="$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' Node_X)" --overprovisioned 1 --smp 1
```

For Status Checking used this command

```
docker exec -it Node_Z nodetool status
```

And blessed with the error:

```
nodetool: Unable to connect to Scylla API server: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
See 'nodetool help' or 'nodetool help <command>'.
```

So as usual i docker logged Node_Z which is not connecting and found out

```
FATAL: Exception during startup, aborting: std::runtime_error (Could not setup Async I/O: Resource temporarily unavailable. The most common cause is not enough request capacity in /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr. Try increasing that number or reducing the amount of logical CPUs available for your application)
```

Fair enough, i got to their documentation and found that we can increase value of aio-max-nr using `echo "fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576" >> /etc/sysctl.conf` but before that we need to locate this file, FROM HERE the real problem started I used this command to located file but blessed with another error

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr
cat: /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr: No such file or directory
```

For save changing we use this and it's giving:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl: illegal option -- p
usage: sysctl [-bdehiNnoqx] name[=value] ...
       sysctl [-bdehNnoqx] -a
```

Used other techniques such as

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.aio-max-nr=1048576
sysctl: unknown oid 'fs.aio-max-nr'
```

Then **another** technique

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf

fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
```

After that the used **another** technique:

```
docker exec -it Node_Z bash
```

Then after entering into bash, change aio-max-nr using:

```
sudo sysctl fs.aio-max-nr=1048576
sysctl: setting key "fs.aio-max-nr", ignoring: Read-only file system
```

it will change that number, you can check using:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr
```

but in my case value wasn't changed, it remains:

```
65536
```

then i found out that There's **Read-Only restriction** so i tried to change the File method to **Read and Write** using :

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
mount: /: permission denied.
```

This is as far as i got and don't know how to deal with it after spending days. Some says that **MAC OS** uses different values as `kern.aiomax` instead `fs.aio-max-nr` but `kern.aiomax` is not able to take value as large as `fs.aio-max-nr=1048576` which is necessary to resolve this error.
HELP ME EXPERTS.

DEVICE:

```
MacBook Pro
Intel Chip
MAC OS VENTURA Version 13.6.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade ScyllaDb to 4.5.0.

instead of creating **all nodes (in your case Node_X, Node_Y, Node_Z)** with 5.2.0 use 4.5.0

```
docker run --name Node_Z -d scylladb/scylla:4.5.0 --seeds="$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' Node_X)" --overprovisioned 1 --smp 1
```

It will run your three nodes but **NOT MORE THEN THREE NODES OR MULTIPLE DATA Centers ON MAC OS.**